# Hibernate entity in tomcat session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat6

I have a web application writtend in java using hibernate and spring.

In my application i need to load one big hibernate entity, attach and re-attach it on tomcat session (like a wizard) and at the end save this modified entity.

*Is there a way to attach and re-attach the entity to hibernate session?*

Actually, I need to map all the sub entities with fetchMode EAGER...otherwise I have the lazyinitializationexception. I've tried with "hibernateSession.lock(entity, LockMode.NONE)" but it doesn't work.

The second problem I have, happened saving the entity; infact, before call the merge method on the entity DAO, I need to reload the entity from DataBase and after merge entity, otherwise deleted entity's data will not be removed from DataBase...
that's sounds to me very strange!

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The web session is completely separate of hibernate. You'll be serializing the entity (and its subcomponents) and then deserializing the altered entity back.

> infact, before call the merge method on the entity DAO, I need to
>   reload the entity from DataBase

That is incorrect, merge :

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier.

Comment: So, for the first problem I think there's nothing to do, while for the second problem (entity merge) what's the solution? Do you need some code's sample?

Comment: What happens when you call merge with an entity that has the correct id assigned ? What do you expect to happen, and what happens ? Write a test/look at the logs. Then show the code here ...

Comment: When I call merge the entity's properties and subclasses are inserted or updated, so it semms to work fine...but if I remove one element mapped as ontToMany, it isn't removed from DataBase...so I expect that it will be deleted. While if, before merge, I load the entoty again the element is deleted from database...